# Add dots to specific points in "timeline"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've created a figure that displays a "timeline" that contains specific points as well as ranges. The only thing that I want to add (but don't know how) are dots/circles/squares at the points (at 0, theta * s, theta*s+w and z). Also, I would like to center the timeline. When I wrap the tikzpicture in the figure environment, no output is created.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

    \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style = {align=center},
          Line/.style = {-angle 90, shorten >=2pt},
    Brace/.style args = {#1}{semithick, decorate, decoration={brace,#1,raise=20pt,
                             pre=moveto,pre length=2pt,post=moveto,post length=2pt,}},
            ys/.style = {yshift=#1}
                    ]
\linespread{0.8}                    
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate[right=30mm of a]    (b);
\coordinate[right=30mm of b]    (c);
\coordinate[right= 20mm of c]    (d);
\coordinate[right=24mm of d]    (e);
\coordinate[right= 5mm of e]    (f);
\coordinate[right=22mm of f]    (g);

\draw[Line] (a) -- (g) node[right] {x};

\draw[Brace=mirror] (a) -- node[below=20pt] {Compensation} (b);
\draw[Brace=mirror] (b) -- node[below=20pt] {Gift} (d);

\draw ([ys=0mm] a) node[below] {0} -- (a);
\draw ([ys=0mm] b) node[below] {$\theta s$} -- (b);
\draw[Line] ([ys=10mm]  c) node[above] {$\delta$} -- (c);
\draw[Line] ([ys=10mm]  d) node[above] {$x(\delta)$} -- (d);
\draw ([ys=0mm]  d) node[below] {$\theta s + w$} -- (d);

\draw ([ys=0mm]  f) node[below] {z} -- (f);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

This is my current output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't know `tikz`, but just playing with it, I came up with this.  It involved adding `*` specs to the Line `\draw` macros, changing the default shorten value, modifying it as necessary.

EDITED for centering (an oversized image), using a `center` environment plus `\makebox[\textwidth]{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style = {align=center},
          Line/.style = {-angle 90, shorten <=-2pt},
    Brace/.style args = {#1}{semithick, decorate, decoration={brace,#1,raise=20pt,
                             pre=moveto,pre length=2pt,post=moveto,post length=2pt,}},
            ys/.style = {yshift=#1}
                    ]
\linespread{0.8}                    
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate[right=30mm of a]    (b);
\coordinate[right=30mm of b]    (c);
\coordinate[right= 20mm of c]    (d);
\coordinate[right=24mm of d]    (e);
\coordinate[right= 5mm of e]    (f);
\coordinate[right=22mm of f]    (g);

\draw[Line,*-] (a) --  (g) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[Line, *-] (b) --  (c) ;
\draw[Line, *-] (d) --  (e) ;
\draw[Line, *-] (f) --  (g) ;

\draw[Brace=mirror] (a) -- node[below=20pt] {Compensation} (b);
\draw[Brace=mirror] (b) -- node[below=20pt] {Gift} (d);

\draw ([ys=0mm] a) node[below] {0} -- (a);
\draw ([ys=0mm] b) node[below] {$\theta s$} -- (b);
\draw[Line, shorten >=4pt] ([ys=10mm]  c) node[above] {$\delta$} -- (c);
\draw[Line, shorten >=4pt] ([ys=10mm]  d) node[above] {$x(\delta)$} -- (d);
\draw ([ys=0mm]  d) node[below] {$\theta s + w$} -- (d);

\draw ([ys=0mm]  f) node[below] {$z$} -- (f);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Also tried to add "*" for the dots but wasn't successful. Thx again! I tried to add a \caption{} and a \label{} between \end{tikzpicture}} and
\end{center} but no caption or label were generated. Where in the code do I implement the label and the caption?